# ¿Hay algún comando que me permita darle poner al revés una variable?

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy haciendo un script que sirva para decir si un numero es capicúa o no. Ahora estoy con numeros de 4 cifras y ese comando me faciliatria mucho el trabajo.

Estoy dividiendo la variable `$numero` con:

```
x=$( echo $numero | cut -c 1,2 )
y=$( echo $numero | cut -c 3,4 )
```

y luego con un `if` los igualaría.

Comment: Deberías añadir la etiqueta del lenguaje que quieres usar, entiendo que bash.
Tu problema se soluciona con un bucle que recorra del inicio hasta la mitad de los números mirando si el numero de la posición i el del final - posición son iguales , solo que encuentre uno que no lo sea, sal del bucle y devuelve false, si lo son todos, true.

Answer (score 7):

Para mostrar una cadena de texto al revés basta con utilizar `rev`:

```
rev <<< "hola"
```

O de esta forma:

```
echo "hola" | rev
```

En ambos caso el resultado sería:

```
"aloh"
```

Saludos.